# Can I use int in multithreaded C++ safely?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have the following code. Is there anything that would make it non-threadsafe?

```
class runner
{
public:
    volatile int exitFlag;

    // construct in thread A
    runner()
    {
        exitFlag = 0;
    }

    // run it in thread B
    void threadFunc()
    {
        // does not matter when the change is getting here
        while (exitFlag == 0)
        {
            // ... do stuff (not using exitFlag)
        }
    }

    // call it from thread A
    void signalThread()
    {
        exitFlag = 1; // only change one bit;
    }
};
```

I create a `runner` object and start it's `threadFunc` in another thread and some time later call `signalThread` on it from the first thread.
I was told that accessing the same variable in different threads (at least of them is write) could lead to reading garbage value. But obviously in the above code (since only one bit is changed) it doesn't matter.
Also the order of read/write is not matter.

Comment: You should use `std::atomic<int>` instead.

Comment: I understand. Could you please state what problems could arise from my code?

Comment: `volatile` doesn't help anything for thread safety. It's a common beginners misconception. You'll need some synchronization mechanism to access the value safely from concurring threads. E.g. something like a [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) will do. Also the mentioned `std::atomic<int>` is suitable.

Comment: What would go wrong in this particular example without synchronization?

Comment: If you don't do it properly, then *for example* changes in one thread might not be seen in another thread in timely manner. In C++, `volatile` does not give any guarantees about this (though in some platforms it may have side-effect of doing this, you can't be sure), you must use proper atomic variable types.

Comment: By timely manner do you mean that the change wouldn't reach thread B?
I stated that the time it arrives doesn't matter just need to happen.

Comment: @user2069848 The change might for example be stuck in the local cache of one CPU core, and not be seen by another core running another thread, until something triggers cache synchronization.

Comment: I see. How does using mutexes gurantee that not happening?

Comment: @user2069848: Mutexes are required to provide synchronisation, and do so using platform-specific facilities such as memory barriers.

Comment: If im correct using mutexes is much slower than simple read write so i'd like to investigate further and find out how can it be done without them. But i may end up using them.

Comment: Atomic types typically don't use mutexes. They use the most effective mechanism available on the platform, whatever it is. You can examine how it is done by getting compiler to output assembly (remember to enable optimizations to get the best assembly).

Comment: See also: http://cxx.isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/

Comment: @user2069848 Mutexes are slower, but there's always https://gist.github.com/rmartinho/5363882

Comment: What does the documentation for whatever threading library/standard you are using say? If it says that you can use `volatile` this way, then you can. If it doesn't, then you can't.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

To sum up the comments (mostly from Mike Seymour)

- One should use `std::atomic` when available
- If not then mutexes and memory barriers come to scope

The posted code contains undefined behaviour (stated by c++ standard)
but the only specific problem that could arise is thread B not getting the changes in reasonable time because they are stuck in cpu chache.

Comment: Why do you post your own summary, when Mike gave such a good answer? Why don't you just accept his instead?

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `volatile` for sharing variables between threads. It does not give suitable guarantees of atomicity or synchronisation. Lack of atomicity is unlikely to cause specific problems here, although formally it causes undefined behaviour. Lack of synchronisation means that it's entirely possible for the thread never to see the change, and carry on running forever.

In C++11 or later, use `std::atomic<int>`. Earlier versions of the language had no standard support for threads, so you'll have to use whatever non-standard facilities your compiler provides.

Comment: Why do i need in this example atomicity or synchronisation?

Comment: @user2069848: Atomicity means you won't read a garbage value during a modification; that's unlikely to happen in your example, but it's better if you can guarantee it. (That's unlikely to be an issue in this specific example; but a guarantee would still be better than an assumption.) Synchronisation means changes made in one thread will be noticed in another; some processors guarantee that, some don't. That will be an issue if `threadFunc` never sees the change to the variable and keeps running forever. `volatile` doesn't affect either of these properties, `std::atomic` does.

Comment: Unlikely? In which scenario could it happen?
I read that declaring the value volatile would make the optimizer issue a memory read/write for every access, instead of trying to keep the value cached in a register thus noticing it in the other thread.
If that is incorrect what does std::atomic use to notifiy the other threads?

Comment: @user2069848: "In which scenario could it happen?" - probably none, as long as the changes are confined to a single byte (or a larger unit, depending on the platform).

Comment: So changing a single bit is always thread safe in this manner?

Comment: @user2069848: "instead of trying to keep the value cached in a register" - that's true, but `volatile` doesn't prevent it being cached in a CPU cache. If the other thread is running on another CPU, with another cache, then it may never see the change. (Some current processors provide hardware-level cache coherency, often at the cost of a huge amount of silicon. But not all do; and not all will be able to in the future, if the number of CPUs gets too large.)

Comment: @user2069848 "So changing a single bit is always thread safe in this manner?" No, because it's not synchronised. As well as formally undefined behaviour, there's no guarantee that the other thread will ever see the change.

Comment: @user2069848: "If that is incorrect what does `std::atomic` use to notifiy the other threads?" It's platform dependent, but typically it uses a *memory barrier* to notify the CPU that the change needs to propagate to other threads.

Comment: So if i include a memory barrier in my code then it will be completly safe?

Comment: @user2069848: Using `std::atomic` is the well-defined, portable way to do this. There's no other portable way to do it.

Comment: @user2069848: "So if i include a memory barrier in my code then it will be completly safe?" I won't say "completely safe" since it's still formally undefined behaviour. But if you include a memory barrier, and don't get that wrong, then it's likely to work. But you really, really should just use `std::atomic`.

Comment: What if i develop on a platform that has no compiler that supports c++11? 
What could 'formally undefined behaviour' result in in this case?

Comment: @user2069848: If you really can't use C++11, then you'll have to put the memory barrier (or a mutex guard, or whatever, according to the specific platform you're developing for) in yourself, using whatever non-standard facilities your compiler provides, and don't try to build the code for another platform. I've no idea what undefined behaviour might do, since it's undefined.

Comment: Could you please point me to a link of a good (cannot decide reliablity from google) article on memory barriers?

Comment: @user2069848: platform specific implementation may actually support correct behavior in this scenario. This is the case for [MS Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) - "When the /volatile:ms compiler option is used—by default when architectures other than ARM are targeted—the compiler generates extra code to maintain ordering among references to volatile objects... This enables volatile objects to be used for memory locks and releases in multithreaded applications." When using such feature code becomes not portable, but it will work on target platform

Comment: @MikeSeymour Your answer assumes his code is C++-11. Otherwise, how do you know what guarantees `volatile` does or doesn't give on his platform or with his threading implementation? This can't be portable code because prior to C++-11, threaded code couldn't be portable. (The claim that it causes UB is valid for C++-11 only. Prior standards don't talk about threads at all.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: There's no "assumption" of C++11; my answer says that there's a solution for C++11 or later, but no portable solution for older dialects (just as you say). And it certainly is UB in older dialects, precisely for the reason you give: they don't talk about (and hence don't define the behaviour of) threads at all.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That's as silly as arguing that all PERL code exhibits UB because the C standard doesn't talk about PERL. Whatever standard or rules he's following when he uses threads that specifies what behavior his code will have (and there must be some), it's not the C++ standard, unless it's C++-11. You have no idea what guarantees his threading library or standard provides, so no way to say whether the behavior is undefined or not. Assuming this isn't C++-11, we know for sure it can't possibly be portable code, so portability arguments are irrelevant. All that matters is his platform.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It's undefined by the C++ standard (prior to C++11), and the question doesn't specify any non-standard threading framework, so it's undefined within the scope of the question. Which is why my answer said "you'll have to use whatever non-standard facilities your compiler provides". I've no idea why you think that's worth arguing about, but there's already been far to much tedious discussion here.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You say "*you'll have to use whatever non-standard facilities your compiler provides*", but what if that's `volatile`? Or what if that's "all integer operations are atomic"? Your answer says that it's undefined by the C++ standard, but that's as irrelevant for a question about threading (again, assuming not C++-11) as it is for a question about PERL.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: If that's how the compiler supports it, then that's what you'd have to do. You may assume "not C++11" for some reason; I answer for the current standard, with a note that older dialects will need a non-standard approach, which I can't provide without knowing which non-standard facilities are available. I still fail to see why you find that controversial; could we please drop this pointless argument?

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact that the data member is not guarded (e.g. by a mutex) makes the code non-threadsafe. Several threads can access the same instance of `runner` (e.g. via a pointer or a reference), and could access `exitflag` simultaneously, since no synchronization mechanism is in place.

To answer the question in your comment: Since `int` is defined as the CPU's "native" type, I believe that a given read or write operation is a single machine code instruction and will not be interrupted by another thread. I don't know whether C/C++ will that guarantee that behavior, though. So in your scenario, it will probably work, although in the general case you need synchronization.

Comment: What if i can guarantee that only thread A accesses exitFlag as write?
Also only thread B reads it.

Comment: @user2069848: You would have more than one thread accessing the same variable concurrently and at least one is a _writer_. That is the definition of a __data race__ and it's __undefined behavior__ in C++. You need synchronization in order for your code to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what has been said, although slightly buried it would seem since you're not saying you understand:

When the value is changed on one CPU it will mostly/usually only get written to the cache of that CPU. Other CPU's will not see it - other threads should NOT be working with exactly the same memory without applying synchronisation techniques!

This changed word of memory may eventually be flushed out to the main memory, but how long that takes is totally unpredictable. Also, if other CPU's think they have that same word of memory in their own cache, they may not go looking for another copy until such times as they discard that piece of memory and later fetch it again.

Mutexes use 'memory barriers' which are basically mechanisms in the CPU and sub-system which allows a thread to say "I want to see TRUE values of all data changed before and under the influence of this mutex. Thus, when one thread acquires a lock on a mutex, modifies a piece of memory, and releases the mutex, ANY other thread that acquires that mutex will be guaranteed to see all memory changed under the guardianship of that mutex.

You MUST use mutexes or other sync objects in a multithreaded system, ESPECIALLY now in this age of multi-core CPU's. Back in the single-core days, you would have gotten away with what you are proposing; the only risk back then would have been broken atomicity. Even a simple machine word can suffer broken read/modify/write cycles on a single core machine, let alone multi-core...